# Rails 6 Upgrade Not Loading Mongoid From a Concern

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, mongoid

We're upgrading our app from Ruby 2.7 to 3.0 and Rails 5.2 to 6.0 at the same time (I started with just Ruby but 3.0 doesn't seem to be compatible with 5.2).  It's close but getting an odd error: `uninitialized constant UserFields::Boolean (NameError)` on start up when we have our user model's fields split off into a concern:

```
class User
  include Mongoid::Document
  include Mongoid::Timestamps
  #field :force_password_change, type: Boolean, default: false
  include UserFields
  ....
end
```

```
module UserFields
  extend ActiveSupport::Concern

  included do
    ## Database authenticatable
    field :email,              :type => String, :default => ""
    field :force_password_change, type: Boolean, default: false  ### <<<< ERROR HERE
  end
end
```

If I put the Boolean fields directly in the model, it works fine but not when they are in the concern.  The error trace:

```
 ! Unable to load application: NameError: uninitialized constant UserFields::Boolean
2024-01-10 15:22:22 bundler: failed to load command: puma (/app/bundle_cache/ruby/3.0.0/bin/puma)
2024-01-10 15:22:22 /app/app/models/concerns/user_fields.rb:8:in `block in <module:UserFields>': uninitialized constant UserFields::Boolean (NameError)
2024-01-10 15:22:22     from /app/bundle_cache/ruby/3.0.0/gems/activesupport-6.0.6.1/lib/active_support/concern.rb:122:in `class_eval'
2024-01-10 15:22:22     from /app/bundle_cache/ruby/3.0.0/gems/activesupport-6.0.6.1/lib/active_support/concern.rb:122:in `append_features'
2024-01-10 15:22:22     from /app/app/models/user.rb:9:in `include'
2024-01-10 15:22:22     from /app/app/models/user.rb:9:in `<class:User>'
2024-01-10 15:22:22     from /app/app/models/user.rb:4:in `<main>'
2024-01-10 15:22:22     from /app/bundle_cache/ruby/3.0.0/gems/bootsnap-1.17.0/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:32:in `require'
2024-01-10 15:22:22     from /app/bundle_cache/ruby/3.0.0/gems/bootsnap-1.17.0/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:32:in `require'
2024-01-10 15:22:22     from /app/bundle_cache/ruby/3.0.0/gems/zeitwerk-2.6.12/lib/zeitwerk/kernel.rb:30:in `require'
2024-01-10 15:22:22     from /app/bundle_cache/ruby/3.0.0/gems/activesupport-6.0.6.1/lib/active_support/inflector/methods.rb:282:in `const_get'
2024-01-10 15:22:22     from /app/bundle_cache/ruby/3.0.0/gems/activesupport-6.0.6.1/lib/active_support/inflector/methods.rb:282:in `block in constantize'
2024-01-10 15:22:22     from /app/bundle_cache/ruby/3.0.0/gems/activesupport-6.0.6.1/lib/active_support/inflector/methods.rb:280:in `each'
2024-01-10 15:22:22     from /app/bundle_cache/ruby/3.0.0/gems/activesupport-6.0.6.1/lib/active_support/inflector/methods.rb:280:in `inject'
2024-01-10 15:22:22     from /app/bundle_cache/ruby/3.0.0/gems/activesupport-6.0.6.1/lib/active_support/inflector/methods.rb:280:in `constantize'
2024-01-10 15:22:22     from /app/bundle_cache/ruby/3.0.0/gems/activesupport-6.0.6.1/lib/active_support/dependencies/zeitwerk_integration.rb:19:in `constantize'
2024-01-10 15:22:22     from /app/bundle_cache/ruby/3.0.0/gems/devise-4.9.3/lib/devise.rb:325:in `get'
2024-01-10 15:22:22     from /app/bundle_cache/ruby/3.0.0/gems/devise-4.9.3/lib/devise/mapping.rb:83:in `to'
2024-01-10 15:22:22     from /app/bundle_cache/ruby/3.0.0/gems/devise-4.9.3/lib/devise/mapping.rb:78:in `modules'
2024-01-10 15:22:22     from /app/bundle_cache/ruby/3.0.0/gems/devise-4.9.3/lib/devise/mapping.rb:95:in `routes'
2024-01-10 15:22:22     from /app/bundle_cache/ruby/3.0.0/gems/devise-4.9.3/lib/devise/mapping.rb:162:in `default_used_route'
2024-01-10 15:22:22     from /app/bundle_cache/ruby/3.0.0/gems/devise-4.9.3/lib/devise/mapping.rb:72:in `initialize'
2024-01-10 15:22:22     from /app/bundle_cache/ruby/3.0.0/gems/devise-4.9.3/lib/devise.rb:361:in `new'
2024-01-10 15:22:22     from /app/bundle_cache/ruby/3.0.0/gems/devise-4.9.3/lib/devise.rb:361:in `add_mapping'
2024-01-10 15:22:22     from /app/bundle_cache/ruby/3.0.0/gems/devise-4.9.3/lib/devise/rails/routes.rb:243:in `block in devise_for'
2024-01-10 15:22:22     from /app/bundle_cache/ruby/3.0.0/gems/devise-4.9.3/lib/devise/rails/routes.rb:242:in `each'
2024-01-10 15:22:22     from /app/bundle_cache/ruby/3.0.0/gems/devise-4.9.3/lib/devise/rails/routes.rb:242:in `devise_for'
2024-01-10 15:22:22     from /app/config/routes.rb:264:in `block in <main>'
2024-01-10 15:22:22     from /app/bundle_cache/ruby/3.0.0/gems/actionpack-6.0.6.1/lib/action_dispatch/routing/route_set.rb:426:in `instance_exec'
2024-01-10 15:22:22     from /app/bundle_cache/ruby/3.0.0/gems/actionpack-6.0.6.1/lib/action_dispatch/routing/route_set.rb:426:in `eval_block'
2024-01-10 15:22:22     from /app/bundle_cache/ruby/3.0.0/gems/actionpack-6.0.6.1/lib/action_dispatch/routing/route_set.rb:408:in `draw'
2024-01-10 15:22:22     from /app/config/routes.rb:1:in `<main>'
```

It stems from the routes file since we use Devise and that is using the User model. I'm sure it has to do with the upgrade as the same code has worked for years in 5.2/2.7.  Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Update**: It is likely this has to do with an upgrade to your `mongoid` gem. I am not certain what version you were previously using but it appears that < 7.3 defined the top level constant `::Boolean` which would allow this to resolve appropriately if you just wrote `Boolean` [Source](https://github.com/mongodb/mongoid/blob/v7.2.6/lib/mongoid/criteria/queryable/extensions.rb#L5). Newer versions do not include this top level constant.

[Release Notes](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/mongoid/current/release-notes/mongoid-7.3/#--boolean-removed) state:

> `::Boolean` Removed
>
> ...code that is not executed in the context of a class including Mongoid::Document may need to explicitly qualify Boolean references.
>
> ...Additionally, in Mongoid 7.2 `::Boolean` and `Mongoid::Boolean` were different classes. In Mongoid 7.3 there is only one class which is `Mongoid::Boolean`.

Since your concern is evaluated outside of the context of the class that includes `Mongoid::Document` you will need to explicitly qualify the constant as  `Mongoid::Boolean`.

e.g.

```
module UserFields
  extend ActiveSupport::Concern

  included do
    ## Database authenticatable
    field :email,                 type: String,           default: ""
    field :force_password_change, type: Mongoid::Boolean, default: false  
  end
end
```

Comment: Brilliant! Work around did the trick.  I might play around with classic loader and read the Zeitwerk docs again and see if I missed anything.  Thanks!

Comment: If the real constant is `Mongoid::Boolean`, I cannot see from those snippets how is it possible that it was resolved before, because `Mongoid` is nowhere in `user_fields.rb`. Was there additional code around?

Comment: @timsegraves see updated post as to why this used to work and no longer does.

Comment: @XavierNoria I was having the same thought so I looked into it a bit more and it appears this was a breaking design change made by `mongoid`. I completely agree with the change given that `::Boolean` and `Mongoid::Boolean` actually referred to different classes, which is an awkward design pattern to begin with.

Comment: @engineersmnky awesome, good finding, now that squares!

Comment: Ah, great finds.  I totally missed that in the mongoid docs as well.  Makes sense for sure.